# Assign TPoupMenu to Inplace editor in the TAdvColumnGrid

Tags: delphi, popupmenu, tms

I am working on `TAdvColumnGrid` where I am facing one issue with the `PopupMenu`.
I have assign a Popup Menu to the Grid. When the cell in the grid is selected/focused then on right click of Mouse button I can show the PopupMenu.

but if the column cell is in `edit mode` and I clicked `right mouse` button then the `default windows Popup` appear.

I want same popup to be shown as it is showing on cell selection.

Please find the below images of both the popup.
[image: Popup 1 and default Popup]

please let me know if any more information is needed.

Thanks and regards,
Ankit Balbudhe

Comment: What do TMS say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You havent't mentioned version that you use. But for example for **TAdvColumnGrid** version 3.1.3.9 you could override the [**CreateEditor**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomGrid.CreateEditor) method:

```
type
  TAdvColumnGrid = class(AdvCGrid.TAdvColumnGrid)
  protected
    function CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TAdvColumnGrid }

function TAdvColumnGrid.CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit;
begin
  Result := inherited;
  if Result is TAdvInplaceEdit then
    TAdvInplaceEdit(Result).PopupMenu := PopupMenu; { ← assign to editor popup menu }
end;
```

Comment: Thanks @Victoria.
This works for me. I am using TMS version 3.1.4.4.   
Is this resolved in the newer version of TMS?

Comment: You're welcome! Well, I wouldn;t say so. It's not actually a bug. Besides, they mention in the [TAdvStringGrid developers guide](http://www.tmssoftware.biz/download/manuals/TMS%20TAdvStringGrid%20Developers%20Guide.pdf) FAQ _"I want to override the popup menu of the default grid inplace editor"_ how to do the same without intercepting the control.